# Missing error message from Selenium after button click

Tags: selenium, phpunit

I'm doing a simple form submit using the click method:

```
$this->url('/');
$move = $this->byName('move');
$move->click();
$content = $this->byTag('body')->text();
```

But I can't understand the error message I get from Selenium:

```
PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase_WebDriverException:
Build info: version: '3.6.0', revision: '6fbf3ec767', time: '2017-09-27T16:15:40.131Z'
System info: host: 'olle-GA-H81M-S2H', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.4.0-51-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_141'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{moz:profile=/tmp/rust_mozprofile.EeZF7cCPXFo3, rotatable=false, timeouts={implicit=0, pageLoad=300000, script=30000}, pageLoadStrategy=normal, moz:headless=false, platform=LINUX, specificationLevel=0, moz:accessibilityChecks=false, acceptInsecureCerts=false, browserVersion=56.0, platformVersion=4.4.0-51-generic, moz:processID=6598, browserName=firefox, javascriptEnabled=true, platformName=LINUX}]
Session ID: eae99c32-7401-4892-9190-e242b3b81f5a
```

I can `var_dump` the `$move` button and confirm that is no null. Any ideas?

The PHP backtrace:

```
vendor/phpunit/phpunit-selenium/PHPUnit/Extensions/Selenium2TestCase/Driver.php:165
vendor/phpunit/phpunit-selenium/PHPUnit/Extensions/Selenium2TestCase/Driver.php:175
vendor/phpunit/phpunit-selenium/PHPUnit/Extensions/Selenium2TestCase/CommandsHolder.php:100
tests/questions/DateTimeValidationTest.php:215
vendor/phpunit/phpunit-selenium/PHPUnit/Extensions/Selenium2TestCase.php:371
vendor/phpunit/phpunit-selenium/PHPUnit/Extensions/Selenium2TestCase.php:337
```

**Edit**: Above was the gecko driver. I get a similar error for the Facebook driver:

```
Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\UnrecognizedExceptionException: 
Build info: version: '3.6.0', revision: '6fbf3ec767', time: '2017-09-27T16:15:40.131Z'
System info: host: 'olle-GA-H81M-S2H', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.4.0-51-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_141'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{moz:profile=/tmp/rust_mozprofile.TpTQ5MWyL1hl, rotatable=false, timeouts={implicit=0, pageLoad=300000, script=30000}, pageLoadStrategy=normal, moz:headless=false, platform=LINUX, specificationLevel=0, moz:accessibilityChecks=false, acceptInsecureCerts=false, browserVersion=56.0, platformVersion=4.4.0-51-generic, moz:processID=9146, browserName=firefox, javascriptEnabled=true, platformName=LINUX}]
Session ID: 56036593-dc86-4132-9d0f-78beb369b35c

vendor/facebook/webdriver/lib/Exception/WebDriverException.php:158
vendor/facebook/webdriver/lib/Remote/HttpCommandExecutor.php:320
vendor/facebook/webdriver/lib/Remote/RemoteWebDriver.php:535
vendor/facebook/webdriver/lib/Remote/RemoteExecuteMethod.php:40
vendor/facebook/webdriver/lib/Remote/RemoteWebElement.php:81
tests/questions/FacebookDriverTest.php:42
```

The HTML for the button is:

```
<button type="submit" value="movesubmit" name="move" accesskey="l" class="ls-move-btn ls-move-submit-btn btn btn-lg btn-primary">
    Submeter
</button>
```

**Edit 2**: Exception from selenium:

```
15:35:15.177 INFO - Executing: [find element: By.name: move])
15:35:15.193 INFO - Done: [find element: By.name: move]
1509374115699   addons.productaddons    INFO    downloadXHR File download. status=200
1509374115702   addons.productaddons    INFO    Downloaded file will be saved to /tmp/tmpaddon-e50bf4
1509374116634   DeferredSave.webext.sc.lz4      DEBUG   Starting write
1509374116639   DeferredSave.webext.sc.lz4      DEBUG   Write succeeded
15:35:17.196 INFO - Executing: [click: 0 [[FirefoxDriver: firefox on LINUX (32c1dfec-9af4-448f-86fa-3a41035bf6b5)] -> name: move]])
15:35:17.501 WARN - Exception thrown
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException:
```

**Edit 3**: Mystery solved, I had two buttons with the same name, and the first one was hidden. Hence, the exception. Solved by putting a proper ID on the element I want to interact with.

Comment: Could you add the html code for the button?

Comment: @Anand Done. Also added error message from Facebook WebDriver.

Comment: Can you give the old fashioned way a try? By saying: $driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::name('move'))->click(); Just so we can see if the exception is still occuring

Comment: @Anand Thanks, yes, it's the same problem. See my latest edit: `org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException`.

Comment: Could you try adding a thread sleep of a few seconds before the click, just to determine if it is a timing issue or not?

Comment: Usually when I see an `ElementNotInteractableException` it's because you're not using the element you think you are. It can also be because of timing issues, where the element is not quite ready to interact with yet. I would use chrome dev tools to inspect the element, and see if what you get is something that either contains the `[name=move]` element or is found within it, and change your selector accordingly. This also occurs if there is some backdrop that is preventig clicks, like when there is a modal popup for example.

Comment: Further explanation, I've seen plenty of `button` elements in **html** with a size of 0, and the element you want to click is the `div` containing it for example.

Comment: @mrfreester You are correct! I had two buttons of this kind - the first was hidden, hence the exception. Now I've put a proper id on the button instead. Mystery solved.